another way to authenticate user without PasswordEncoder (in Spring boot)
import statements;

@Configuration
public class AppSecurity {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        JdbcUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);
        userDetailsManager.setUsersByUsernameQuery("SELECT mobile, pin, 1 AS enabled FROM users WHERE mobile = ?");
        userDetailsManager.setAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT mobile, 'ROLE_USER' FROM users WHERE mobile = ?");
        return userDetailsManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filter(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(configure ->
                    configure.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/**")
                            .hasRole("USER")
                            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**")
                            .hasRole("USER")
                );


        http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }
}


this is my configuration class
this config class allow user to login with their mobileno and pin .
i am storing the password as plain text (noop).
and i am storing the passowrds in database without encryption id (ex: {noop}, {bcrypt} ...)
but the
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
} 

Intellij shows NoOpPasswordEncoder is deprecated
is there any other way to achieve the authentication
Note: I am storing the passwords without the encrypt id i.e,. '0000' not '{noop}0000'

Don't store password in plain text, ever, period... From the docs of NoOpPasswordEncoder:

This PasswordEncoder is not secure. Instead use an adaptive one way function like BCryptPasswordEncoder, Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder, or SCryptPasswordEncoder. Even better use DelegatingPasswordEncoder which supports password upgrades. There are no plans to remove this support. It is deprecated to indicate that this is a legacy implementation and using it is considered insecure.

The warning is there for a reason, it is a good thing, it will remind you that you are using an insecure encoder. If you want to get rid of it, you can always make your own no op implementation, but that would be circumventing a problem, not fixing it - your implementation will be literary the same and won't suddenly become secure. Use DelegatingPasswordEncoder instead, as suggested in the documentation.

Run a query in your database to add {noop} prefix before every password, or configure the delegating encoder to consider the missing prefix for no op - see setDefaultPasswordEncoderForMatches().

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
  DelegatingPasswordEncoder encoder = (DelegatingPasswordEncoder) PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
  //for backwards compatibility
  //remove once all passwords in db are encoded
  encoder.setDefaultPasswordEncoderForMatches(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
  return encoder;
}


Start encoding newly registered passwords and enforce existing users to change their password (for example on login) - naturally you must encode the new ones.

